# what does DisplayMemberPath="Value" do when trying to bind data?

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am very confused about how DisplayMemberPath="Value" works and what is its purpose. I have copied other peoples code and it never works for me in the way I expect instead I get an error when I click the combo box.

> An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException' occurred in mscorlib.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
>
> Additional information: Object does not match target type.

My code is

```
    <ComboBox Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value" x:Name="comboBox1" FontSize="25"/>

var source = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            source.Add(1,"Item1");
            source.Add(2,"Item2");
            source.Add(3,"Item3");
            source.Add(4,"Item4");

            var formateDSource = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                formateDSource.Add(string.Format("[{0}, {1}]", item.Key, item.Value), item.Key);
            }

            comboBox1.ItemsSource = source;
```

Basically when I run my code I expect to see in my combo box a list like this:

> Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4

Now although I inserted a dictionary with both keys and values I expect my values to be shown in my combo box as above. Is that not what we use DisplayMemberPath="Value" for? So why does it give me the error above?

When I delete DisplayMemberPath="Value" from my code my combo box works but displays this as a list:

> [1,Item1] [2,Item2] [3,Item3] [4,Item4]

which is no good for me because I do not want my user to see the keys just the values. I could change my code to:

```
comboBox1.ItemsSource = source.Values;
```

Which works perfectly but then my combo box does not have the keys for the values and thus making things more difficult for me to get what the user selected or is that the right way to get the result I want rather than DisplayMemberPath="Value". If I am misunderstood can somebody explain the use of DisplayMemberPath="Value" and why my code does not work or how I get the result I want? Sorry just to add for those in doubt. I have tried my code as a wpf application and it works perfectly but as a windows store app it does which is what I need it for. Why is this and is there a way that works for a Windows store application

Comment: What is `formateDSource` for? You do not seem to use it

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? From what you are posting here, it can't be told why `DisplayMemberPath="Value"` doesn't work. It should simply work, and indeed it does work for us others. There must be more in your application, something else that produces this error.

Comment: Are you binding SelectedValue to a type that is not int? This would seem a likely source of your error.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would feed you combobox with some kind of list or collection.

Assume you have a class called Person

```
class Person{
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public int Age{get;set;}
 }
```

Now you can feed you combobox with a list of Persons, but you combobox will display Project.Person or whatever the ToString method shows.

But you in DisplayMemberPath you can speficy Name, and then it will show the Name of the person instead.

Comment: These are perfectly good answers to the question. New here so unsure of the reason for down vote.

Answer (score 0):

When you bind a collection of items of Type X, DisplayMemberPath is used to set which property of X will be used as the display value. It's a simple mechanism for avoiding the need for a data template when you have a nice string value in your item type which can simply be displayed as text. In your example it is looking for a property called Value on your item type.

Comment: Yes. And why doesn't it find that property?

Comment: Can you show your whole xaml file please?